# Can't connect to DB with Tableplus/Laravel forge - wrong username or password

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge, table-plus

I have a Laravel project that I manage with Laravel forge.
The website is provisioned, the database is correctely working.

I can even fully access the DB trough commands on Git bash by doing `ssh forge@<IP_ADRESS>` and `mysql -u root -p <DB_PASSWORD>`

However, if I try to create a new connection on Tableplus by importing it with a Database Connection URL and inserting the DB password I've received when I provisioned the server, I get this error
[image: SSH error]
`SSH Error - Wrong username or password`

I'm only inserting the DB password as explained in the online guides.
[image: New MySQL connection]

I've tried recreating a new server, using a private key that returns "invalid key".
Unfortunately, there is close to none guides online for this particular issue.

What could I do?

Comment: did you connected? im also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the upper section (under 127.0.0.1 ) you should provide `Port: 3306`.
Also, please mind that `user`, `password` and `database` are your database settings, which can be seen in .env under DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD.

For the SSH section (which is under `Over SSH` checkbox) you should provide `Port: 22`. The user is `forge`. Then you should check `Use SSH key` checkbox and provide your SSH private key. There is a lot of info on WEB regarding how to generate it. This key should be added to your Forge `SSH keys` in admin as well.